# text comparison with grep (a.txt contians words, b.txt contains strings, if a string from b.txt contains words form a -> output)

Tags: bash, grep

Simple text comparison: a.txt contains words, b.txt contains strings, if a string from b.txt contains a word or words from a.txt -> c.txt (the string from b.txt, not the word from a.txt)

a.txt

```
CREDIT
```

b.txt

```
CREDITUNION
```

Sourcecode:

```
grep -F -o -f b.txt a.txt | sort | uniq > c.txt
```

Since 'CREDITUNION' contains the word 'CREDIT' in c.txt 'CREDITUNION' have to show up... But its not...

Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have flipped the file containing the pattern with the input file.

Specify the file containing the *words* as an argument to `-f`, and the file containing the *strings* as the input file to `grep`.  Moreover, remove the `-o` option else you would see the *words* in the output and not the *strings*, e.g. you'd see `CREDIT` instead of `CREDITUNION`:

```
grep -F -f a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq > c.txt
```

Comment: Now c.txt contains 'CREDIT' instead of 'CREDITUNION'

Comment: @fobiss Are you sure that you haven't supplied the `-o` option?

Comment: Sorry, it was there. Btw, now for test imput it is working, for the real imput files, the c.txt contains nothing :( Can I send you somehow my files for you?

Comment: @fobiss It looks like your input files have CR+LF line endings.  Run `dos2unix` on your input files to remove the CR before `grep`.

Comment: Can I do that stuff on my mac?

Comment: @fobiss Yes.  `tr -d '\r' < a.txt > temp && mv temp a.txt`  Likewise for the other file.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Douglas, that was the problem! :)